# PROBLEMA AL CARGAR LIBERIA FPDF EN CODEIGNITER 4

Tags: php7, fpdf

Estoy tratando de caragr la libreria FPDF  y me sale el siguient error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo estoy tratando de cargar o llamar desde mi controlador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

necesito su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

ya solucione mi problema,solo coloquen esto en su autoload y listo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código tanto de la pregunta como de la respuesta va como código